# Change stroke color of shape - EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

I want to change the stroke color of a line (on click press) drawn as:

```
var currentLine = new createjs.Shape();
currentLine.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY).setStrokeStyle(4).beginStroke(tempLineColor).lineTo(target.x, target.y).endStroke();
```

I tried the "command" property of the graphics (currentLine.graphics.command) as mentioned here: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html

But it didnt work because it returns "undefined".
Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/86f7gz6b/19/

Comment: It's working. There may be problem with your parameters. See this feedle http://jsfiddle.net/86f7gz6b/1/

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur My question was not related to "How to draw a line" :)
I am able to draw a line successfully but I want to change its color on mouse click. Hope you would get my question now :)

Comment: In that case you have to use mouse interaction http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mouse%20Interaction/ and you have to redraw that same line.

Comment: Can't I update just the stroke color of the line without having to redraw it?

Comment: It's canvas it doesn't remember shapes like mspaint so we have redraw them for changing colors. Make fiddle of your work and post. Alternatively you can go with SVG if you want.

Comment: I was curious if I can change just the stroke color of the line because I found a method "set" of graphics object. I changed the alpha of the line on click.
updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/86f7gz6b/19/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fiddle you provided uses an old version of CreateJS from 2013, which did not have support for Graphics commands (commands were added in version 0.8.0, released in December 2014). I have updated your fiddle with the latest (0.8.2), but note that JSFiddle also has 0.8.1 (part of CreateJS 2015.05.21), which would work as well.

The command approach is simple, just store off the last graphics.command, and modify its style value later.

```
shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(4);
var cmd = shape.graphics.beginStroke("red").command; // <- note the command
shape.graphics.moveTo(0,0).lineTo(100,100);
stage.update();
// Later
cmd.style = "blue";
stage.update();
```

You can also chain instructions, and `.command` will return the last instruction command:

```
// Gets the beginStroke command
var cmd = shape.graphics.setStrokeStyle(4).graphics.beginStroke("red").command;
```

There was one thing I had to change to make your example work: The initial `moveTo` command has to be put *after* the beginStroke, as starting a stroke or fill will reset the path command, so your example wouldn't work (EaselJS must have an initial moveTo in order for a single lineTo to work.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/86f7gz6b/21/

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you so much Lanny for pointing out the mistake. I was using the old version of easeljs (ver. 0.7.1) in my project which was causing the trouble. I updated it to 0.8.2 and now its working fine :)